# prove that $\lim_{}\frac{1}{3^{n}} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Because

$$\frac{1}{3^{n}}< \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{3^{n-2}}< \epsilon $$

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon }< 3^{n-2} $$

and

$$\frac{1}{3^{n-2} }<\epsilon$$

because

$$ \frac{1}{3^{n}}< \frac{1}{3^{n-2}} and \frac{1}{3^{n-2}}< \epsilon $$

By transitivity property

$$\frac{1}{3^{n}}< \epsilon $$

therefore the limit converge to 0

Comment: The question and title don't seem to match. Are you in a hurry to type questions? Don't worry, we are not going anywhere.

Comment: I already edited it ^ ^

Comment: Why change $n$ to $n-2$? The rest is completely fine.

Comment: I think if I change it it make the inequality hold.But I think It has a flaw might not hold in some condition ,but I don't know.

Comment: Uhm... It's the second or third question like this I've seen you write, and personally I have the same doubt: the definition of limit says that for all $\epsilon>0$ there must be $N_\epsilon$ such that for all $n\ge N_\epsilon$ it holds $\left\lvert\frac1{3^n}\right\rvert<\epsilon$. For all your inequalities, algebraic manipulations and stuff, can you describe in, like, one line such $N_\epsilon$? Because I think you are consistently using circular arguments in these exercises.

Comment: @Fourier You should have more confidence in yourself. Everything works out if you take $n$ instead of $n-2$. Even if you had made a mistake, we were here to correct  it, after all.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг thank you :)

Comment: Given that 3^n has a limit I believe we can say that  r(3^n) has limit r(limit 3^n) with r being the reciprocal function because r is continuous. This argument is better than my answer because it appeals more to generality.

Comment: @Fourier You are welcome. By the way, your presentation of questions is very neat, so keep it up. But you can use different environments so that your questions may look more compact, because as you start posting larger proofs you might need to keep the question from not overflowing in space.

Comment: Do you know 1/n goes to 0? This is a subsequence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\forall\ \epsilon > 0\quad \mbox{let}\quad
N = \left\lfloor-\,{\ln\pars{\epsilon} \over \ln\pars{3}}\right\rfloor.\qquad
\mbox{Then,}\quad
\forall\ \epsilon > 0\,,\quad n > N \implies {1 \over 3^{n}} <\epsilon
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bbx{\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over 3^{n}} = 0}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

3^n is unbounded and increasing. Thus 1/3^n gets arbitrarily close to 0 and is decreasing. This is sufficient.